# With money saved for buying a house, part of which put towards an investment which has yet to give returns, what am I obliged to pay for zakaat?

Tags: zakat

I had $120000 five years ago, saved towards buying a house. Out of which I put $60,000 towards an investment expecting a return. To date, I still have not received any returns nor the total amount back. It does not seem likely that i will be able to recover it soon.

The balance has been kept for safekeeping with a member of my family and it is solely for the purpose of buying a house.

What am I obliged to pay for zakaat?

It is unlikely that i will be buying a house very soon.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking our [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you still have $120.000 as your saving. Even though another family member is handling that saving, that saving still belongs to you. Since the amount have fulfilled nishab and the duration of the possesion have fulfilled haul, you stil need to pay zakat for that saving. Because you haven't receive any return and you don't know how many returns you will get, you should only pay zakat for the saving; not the investment.